# ffmpeg command not working on ec2

Tags: ffmpeg, amazon-ec2

I have a command `ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i source-video/test222.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 ./tmp/%d.ts` which break up a video into 10 second segments.  This works on my Mac running ffmpeg 3.0.2 but not on my ec2.  I have posted before and received no responses.  I am trying to take steps to solve this problem and define the problem.  I have now used [this](https://gist.github.com/prashantmaurice/07e52f970cbb1f6d10b5165344623b04) shell script which gets me version `n3.0.5-6-g76961f4`.  It seems that this version is not able to run the command in question as well.  I understand that the shell script is compiling software that it is fetching from the internet.  How can I modify this to fetch version 3.0.2.

Comment: Don't try to match your desktop ffmpeg. OS X and linux have different libraries, so you will not have the same executable anyway. What exactly do you see if you run this command from command line inside EC2 instance?

Comment: Ok, it seems to be working now.  Sorry but on MacOS its just `brew install ffmpeg`.  Here, I had to find a shell script 3 links deep into gist hub comment sections.  I think there were just too many variables to get right.  So in the end, updating to a v 3.* ffmpeg seems to have solved my problems, at least for now.  I wasn't trying to 'match' the exe's but just have approx similar version so the same API was implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you'd want to install packages into your Linux system from a package repository. That is the easiest way to install (its very similar to the "Homebrew" system used on Mac, where `brew` is essentially a "source package manager"), the fastest and allows you to get additional updates in the future with the rest of your system in a single step.

Most common package managers used on Linux are binary package managers and Amazon Linux, like RedHat, CentOS and Fedora use a package manager called "YUM" (in contrast with "Homebrew" discussed above, which is called a "source package manager" because its packages are source code that is downloaded and installed. There are some source package managers on Linux, but its a less common paradigm especially on the server side where you want consistency and fast setup).

As I've mentioned, your operating system already comes with a package manager and is already configured with some repositories - namely the operating system's own repositories. It is common to add other software repositories to allow installing software not offered by the operating system manufacturer in their repositories, like FFMPEG.

For example on Amazon Linux and similar "Enterprise Linux" operating systems its common to add the "EPEL" repositories. Unfortunately those repositories also do not include FFMPEG.

I suggest using the NegativeO17 multimedia repository that includes an up to date FFMPEG as well as a few other goodies. [Easy to follow instructions to set up the repository you can find here](http://negativo17.org/handbrake/) (Please note that you use the `dnf` command instead of `yum` which I mentioned - don't worry about it - DNF is just the new version of YUM).

Comment: thanks.  in the intervening time I ran this script https://gist.github.com/prashantmaurice/07e52f970cbb1f6d10b5165344623b04, which upgraded me to 3.* version which seems to implement the segment command in question properly.  It was messy as and probably less ideal than using a binary PM.  I had to fix some symlinks that the script failed on but ultimately got ffmpeg operational.  I will follow your instructions for the future.

Comment: Hey, @user5797668 - if you think this is the correct answer, please accept it by clicking the checkmark button :-)

Comment: I can't validate whether it was or wasn't as I had already installed a working ffmpeg using a shell script I found.  However, its clearly well-informed and clearly-written so sure.